# Leaflet map "center" option not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map and I want to center it to concrete point. Following implementation is working correctly:

```
 var map = L.map('map', {
                crs: crs
            }
    );

 map.setView([58.66, 25.05], 2);
```

However, implementation below is not working correctly and does not center the map. Why it is happening? I get just blank grey area instead of my map.  According to the documentation it does completely the same as the code above.

```
  var map = L.map('map', {
                    crs: crs,
                    center: L.latLng(58.66, 25.05)
                }
        );
    map.setZoom(2);
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you specify the center option when creating the map you also have to specify the zoom option or leaflet doesn't know what tiles to request.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: L.latLng(58.66, 25.05),
    zoom: 2
});
```

When you use setView, you are setting center and zoom so leaflet knows the tiles to request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: crs,
  center: L.latLng(58.66, 25.05),
  zoom: 2
});
```

?